# Linux sftp upload file from local machine to remote server

Tags: sftp

I am using command prompt. Successful connection to remote server and sftp. I am trying to upload a file from my pc, path: `C:/Users/12534/Desktop/archomework/Hw01_test.pdf` 
to my remote server directory: `/home/albpat03/arc/*.*`
so I use command: `put /Users/12534/Desktop/archomework /home/albpat03/arc/`
with file name or `*.*` and I still get this error:
`stat /Users/12534/Desktop/archomework/Hw01_test.pdf`: No such file or directory
HELP!

Comment: Are you already on C device? Issue a ls command to make sure you see at least the /Users directory.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `scp` instead, it uses the `ssh` protocol.

Try

> scp  /path/to/target/file yourusername@remoteip.com:/path/to/destination/file

Where remoteip.com can be replaced with the IP Address or Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN) of your remote machine.